# iphone dev mp3 file not playing using av audio player

Tags: iphone

i am trying to play an mp3 audio file, the file will be uploaded by user on web server and i will get the url of that file and then i have to play that file but i am not succeeding in it. here is my code

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];
        NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:theData error:nil];
        [newPlayer play];

the url is like this

http://mqm.designers99.com/Notification/mp3_files/1331551313_1919.mp3

Plz. guide me coz i am stuck here, thanx and regards

Comment: P.s. You don't need the `-initWithData:error:` instance method for this, you could just use `-initWithContentsOfURL:error:`

Comment: What iOS version are you deploying on?

Comment: no luck rather it is displaying this error the operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus -43)

Comment: ios version 5 is of my device its ipod 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'reading' the error:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:theData error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioPlayer start playing");
    [newPlayer play];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Any "luck" ?

Comment: nothing i am displaying the error as [error localizedDescription] in an alert, even that alert is not displaying

Comment: rather its displaying this error  the operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus -43)

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413932/audio-playback-does-not-start

Comment: NO its also not working may be i didnt got correct example for playing mp3 from url using av player, do u have any example or something?

Comment: You could try to first download (cache) the mp3 file to your sandbox cache directory and play it from there or take a step back and play the mp3 file from inside your bundle

Answer (score 0):

Include AVFoundation and AudioToolBox frameworks

Import header for that framework in .h file

```
    #import<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
    #import<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Instantiate AVAudioPlayer,

```
    AVAudioPlayer *player
```

Use this code for play audio.It's working fine for me

```
    NSString *url1=@"http://mqm.designers99.com/Notification/mp3_files/1331551313_1919.mp3";

url1=[url1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//Encode your url 

NSLog(@"after encoding========:%@",url1);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1]; 
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:theData error:nil];
[player play];
```

Edit:Without encode the url you given also played well.

Comment: No need to encode the URL nor import the AudioToolbox framework.

Comment: @saad umar:If the answer for your question is helpful for you means please accept my answer and do upvote

Comment: @SaadUmar:have you include the frameworks and import header of that framework?

Comment: @SaadUmar:for me the same code is played well.Then only i post that code