# Why isn't the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying not being executed

Tags: ios6, storyboard, avaudioplayer

I have this audioplayer piece of code and I do not know why the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is not being executed.

Here is part of the code from my audioplayer.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSError* e = nil;
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:self.contentURL];
if(e)
{
    NSLog(@"Detected error(%@)",e);
}

[self.playButton  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed :@"Pause_40_40.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
[self.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

isPlaying = true;

//Title of Music Screen
//self.title = titleOfTheSong;
//self.title = @"A Fixed Title";

MPVolumeView * volmueView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 323, 200, 23)];
volmueView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[self.view addSubview:volmueView];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
e = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&e];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", e);

posUpdateTimer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(timeCounterUpdate) userInfo:self.player repeats:YES];
[self timeCounterUpdate2:self.positionSlider.value];
[self.player play];

}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"Finished");
if (flag == NO){
    return;
}

[self.player pause];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I am setting the name of the avplayer to player in the viewDidload and then checking against that but it still does not seem to be called

The audio stops playing but seems to still be operating the current position value does stop
but the button still shows as if the audio still in the play mode if I pause it and then play it the current position simply continues to count passed the supposed end of the file.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I am trying to utilize preexisting code done by some one not here any longer. Could you please give me an example on how I could fix. I am on the newer side to programming for the iPhone sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, sorry... Well. You have to use `AVAudioPlayer` if all you want is simply playing an audio file. Also, as I just affirmed it in my answer, you must set its delegate (else no delegate methods will be called).

Comment: Well I just found out that AVAudioPlayer does not support HTTP streaming.  Check this post from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413932/audio-playback-does-not-start

Comment: so apparently that was some left over code the previous programmer neglected to take out

Answer (score 0):

Because 1. you don't use an `AVAudioPlayer` but an `AVPlayer`, 2. you don't set the delegate of the audio player object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the issue I was having was in fact due to the previous programmer who had worked on it. He mistakenly tried using the `AVAudioPlayer` to play audiofiles that were not local but needed to be retrieved from a URL. So he migrated the code to `AVPlayer` which does allow but left in the old irrelevant code. I mistakenly saw the code and thought the correct methods were there and was confused by the fact it was not running. Being able to end the file from playing was the piece of the `AVAudioPlayer` functionality the he left in. I have since used the correct coding methods to achieve what I wanted.

Hopefully this will cause the negative mark against my score to be removed, since the code was operating previously but without the functionality I was looking for I made the mistake of thinking that section of code was valid when it was not.